# Truffle test with non-standard deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha

I have a few contracts that I wanted to test using Mocha (that comes with Truffle). These contracts all require parameters in their constructor. I have modified the "2_deploy_contracts.js" file and it works as per requirement.

How do I code my mocha test suite so that I can invoke my customised 2_deploy_contracts.js? It seems the clean-room of Truffle test only works with simple zero-parameter constructors.

Answer (score 1):

When making tests with `truffle test` you can request for deploying contract in the testfile Here is an example of a series of tests i wrote to give an example :

```
var Organizations = artifacts.require("./Organizations.sol");

// Deploy an instance of the contract 
contract('Organizations',function(accounts){
    it("Owner on deployment should be : " + accounts[0],function(){
        return Organizations.new("GroupTest",accounts[0],{from : accounts[0], gas : '2500000'}).then(function(inst){
            return inst.owner();
        }).then(function(r){
            assert.equal(r,accounts[0],"Owner is not : " + accounts[0]);
        });
    });

// Check data keeps coherence  : TODO 
    it("Users should be able to request membership",function(){
        return Organizations.new("GroupTest",accounts[0],{from : accounts[0], gas : '2500000'}).then(function(inst){
           return inst.requestMembership({from: accounts[1], gas : 150000}).then(function(){
               return inst.membershipRequests(accounts[1]);
           }).then(function(r){
                assert.equal(r,true,"User hasn\'t been registered in membership request registry");    
           });
        });
    });
```

Aknowledging the following parts of the contract :

```
contract Organizations{
    string public name;
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => bool) public membershipRequests;

    function Organizations(string _name, address _owner){
        owner = _owner;
        name = _name;
    }

    function requestMembership() returns(bool success){
        membershipRequests[msg.sender] = true;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I invoke the constructor within the test suite, will Truffle knows it and therefore skip its own deployment?
If the deployment is now a test case, is there a easy way for me to define the dependency so that other test cases only run after the deployment is completed?